# What documentation exists to explain TheVolumeSettingsFolder on OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystem, hfs+, disk-volume

Searching Google for the following I only found uninformed crap. What is this?

```
looris@Palace-of-the-Nine-Moons:/tmp $ tree /TheVolumeSettingsFolder/
/TheVolumeSettingsFolder/
└── HFSExtentTables
    └── OVDBHDR4R6PVQJPJRE6QTLCBNS
        ├── 8PHMGCTSVNFUN915KNSCRDST3K
        └── UBNUIHU3QNGCTMAO8ECAQ65960

2 directories, 2 files
```

The two files are binary data (`file` just says "data" and `strings` returns nothing useful).

If they are, as the name would imply, actually "volume settings", how can I know which volume they refer to?

Comment: I couldn't find any definitive documentation, either. The term "HFS extent tables" refers to the data organization scheme of the HFS filesystem, but I don't understand why those would exist as file data instead of metadata. What's the format of your root drive? Do you share the volume over the network?

Comment: @jmk format is HFS+ journaled, and only the public folders of each user are shared.